# Error while installing Android Studio in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install android studio in ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
I downloaded the latest release and installed  jdk using

```
sudo apt install openjdk-9-jre-headless
```

After the above step I am trying to run `./studio.sh` after extracting Android studio zip file but It is giving me the following error. Please help.

```
com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:96)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:93)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.ApplicationNamesInfo.getInstance(ApplicationNamesInfo.java:49)
    at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.getFrameClass(AppUIUtil.java:127)
    at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.updateFrameClass(AppUIUtil.java:120)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:114)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:34)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot load resource: /idea/AndroidStudioApplicationInfo.xml
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.ApplicationNamesInfo.<init>(ApplicationNamesInfo.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.ApplicationNamesInfo.<init>(ApplicationNamesInfo.java:30)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.ApplicationNamesInfo$ApplicationNamesInfoHolder.<clinit>(ApplicationNamesInfo.java:43)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /idea/AndroidStudioApplicationInfo.xml
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.loadDocument(JDOMUtil.java:351)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.ApplicationNamesInfo.<init>(ApplicationNamesInfo.java:55)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw similar problem on StackOverflow. Please, do not install Java 9 before previous would be officially deprecated. This version is still in sdevelopment process and might be highly unstable

Unistall openJdk-9 and install Oracle-jdk-8 following this post:
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html